# Swift: How to play the video and download at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, video, avasset

Currently in our iOS Application, we are downloading the video and then playing it, which is indeed taking a lot of time and killing the user experience. Now, we want to shift to directly stream the video or play the video while it is downloading. 
I have tried using **AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate**. I doesn't play the video at all and displays the mime type as text/html. Maybe because I am loading from a secured URL with headers.

Can someone suggest me a good way where I can stream or Play the video while downloading it. Would be glad if someone suggest a way to Stream the video's directly from the URL.

Comment: When I did something like that I just initialized [`AVAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasset) with video file url and fed it to `AVPlayer` (which was in PlayerViewController). So if you have direct video URL you can try using this way.

Comment: @user28434 Initially I tried doing the same thing! The video player is just displaying a blank screen. So, then I tried using AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and AVUrlAsset, even then no luck!